# Can not open gazebo with roslaunch gazebo_ros empty_world.launch

Tags: gazebo, roslaunch, ros-noetic

I am using ros noetic and gazebo 11.14.0 I tried to open the gazebo with ros `roslaunch gazebo_ros empty_world.launch` but got the following error:

````
[gazebo-2] process has died [pid 88653, exit code 127, cmd /opt/ros/noetic/lib/gazebo_ros/gzserver -e ode worlds/empty.world __name:=gazebo __log:=/home/mubashir/.ros/log/9b668e7e-a1a0-11ee-a94c-919ce4483398/gazebo-2.log].
log file: /home/mubashir/.ros/log/9b668e7e-a1a0-11ee-a94c-919ce4483398/gazebo-2*.log
[gazebo_gui-3] process has died [pid 88658, exit code 127, cmd /opt/ros/noetic/lib/gazebo_ros/gzclient __name:=gazebo_gui __log:=/home/mubashir/.ros/log/9b668e7e-a1a0-11ee-a94c-919ce4483398/gazebo_gui-3.log].
log file: /home/mubashir/.ros/log/9b668e7e-a1a0-11ee-a94c-919ce4483398/gazebo_gui-3*.log

```
````

Answer (score 0):

Gazebo can be tricky. There are different versions. Take a look at Github/Linorobot2 and see how Juan does it. If using Ros1 just choose Linorobot.

Answer (score 0):

If Gazebo is crashing without loading a robot model or any controllers, it could be a corrupted ROS installation. In that case you could try uninstalling all packages starting with `ros-noetic-` and deleting `/opt/ros/*` as well as your catkin workspace, then starting over. This happened to me one time with a binary install, and three times with a source install/build.

If you are curious (or re-installing doesn't work, or perhaps you find that unacceptable) try starting in VSCode with a debugger attached, and check the box for breaking on exceptions. This will work much better with a source build, but you might get something out of it.

Lastly, you could try starting Gazebo in a paused state. A lot of plugins and other functionality like physics is dormant until you start processing time-steps, and that's when a lot of crashes happen. If it doesn't crash when paused, you might be able to attach a debugger and unpause to catch what happens.

```
roslaunch gazebo_ros empty_world.launch paused:=true
```

(or something like that)